# Coverity Static Analysis for Java: Find Inappropriate Exception Handling

Tags: java, exception, static-analysis

We have been testing Coverity Static Analysis for Java (version 5.5.1) for a few months now.  It's great to spot those potential RESOURCE_LEAKs, but we would also like to be able to find inappropriate exception handling.
At the simplest, we would just like to find all places where exceptions are ignored, for example:

```
catch (SomeException se) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

and where top-level exceptions are caught, for example:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrack();
}
```

Coverity's manual talks about using custom modeling, but I'm not sure if this is a proper solution.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Coverity's manual talks about using custom modeling, but I'm not sure if this is a **proper** solution."* - There is certainly nothing wrong with doing that ... if that is what you are asking.

Comment: If all you want to do is to detect these two examples, it appears you can use any kind of tool with a regular search, e.g., Perl.  You'd have to include sub-regexps to ignore comments and whitespace inside the catch blocks.

Comment: PMD does this for you

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a supported ability to write custom checkers for Java as there is for C/C++ but I believe it'll be available in the future.  That's the best way to create checkers that flag specific behavior you want to find (and fix).

Coverity Java analysis also runs FindBugs as part of it - doesn't FB have a warning for catching an exception that isn't thrown?  I believe that might take care of your second case.  I think they have one for empty catch block as well, though I can't find a link to it right now.

Comment: Thanks, Asya.  I think this is what you're referring to: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#REC_CATCH_EXCEPTION.  It doesn't help my case, because some narrower exception like java.lang.IllegalArgumentException was thrown in the try block, where the ensuing catch block catches java.lang.Exception instead.  We would like to discourage this kind of practice, enlisting static analysis's help.

I could not find a checker in http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html that suits the two cases I mentioned...

Comment: some future version of Coverity for Java will probably support writing custom checkers, same as their C/C++ analysis SDK.